# table row is not deleting after click on radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<form method="POST" action="insert.php" name="reg" onsubmit="return chkform();">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" width="" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>1. First Name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" onfocus="document.getElementById('err1').innerHTML='';" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>2. Last Name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" onfocus="document.getElementById('err2').innerHTML='';" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" colspan="2" style="color: red;font-size: 11px;">
            <div class="err" id="err1" style="margin-right: 103px;"></div>
        </td>
        <td align="right" colspan="2" style="color: red;font-size: 11px;">
            <div id="err2"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>3. Mobile Number</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="" id="m_no" name="m_no" onfocus="document.getElementById('err3').innerHTML='';" placeholder="Mobile Number" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>4. Alternate Number</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="" id="a_no" name="a_no" onfocus="document.getElementById('err4').innerHTML='';" placeholder="Alternate Number" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" colspan="2" style="color: red;font-size: 11px;">
            <div id="err3" style="margin-right: 120px;"></div>
        </td>
        <td align="right" colspan="2" style="color: red;font-size: 11px;">
            <div id="err4"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>5. Email address</label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <input type="email" class="" id="mail" name="mail" onfocus="document.getElementById('err5').innerHTML='';" placeholder="Email id" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" colspan="2" style="color: red;font-size: 11px;">
            <div id="err5" style="margin-right: 120px;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>6. Organisation/Designation</label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <input type="text" class="" id="designation" name="designation" onfocus="document.getElementById('err6').innerHTML='';" placeholder="Oraganisation" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" colspan="2" style="color: red;font-size: 11px;">
            <div id="err6" style="margin-right: 141px;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>7. Industry</label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <input type="text" class="" id="industry" name="industry" onfocus="document.getElementById('err7').innerHTML='';" placeholder="Industry" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" colspan="2" style="color: red;font-size: 11px;">
            <div id="err7" style="margin-right: 141px;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="">
            <label>8. Are you a Member?</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" class="" id="rchk1" name="member" value="yes" checked="true" onclick="chk_register()" />
            <label>Yes</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" class="" id="rchk2" name="member" value="no" onclick="chk_register()" />
            <label>No</label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="cit">
        <td>
            <label>9. Member City</label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <input type="text" class="" id="city" name="city" placeholder="Name of the city" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" colspan="4" style="color: red;font-size: 11px;">
            <div id="err8"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="">
            <label>10. Are you an Overseas Delegate?</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" id="rchk3" value="yes" name="overseas" checked="true" class="" onclick="chk_register1()" />
            <label>Yes</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" value="no" id="rchk4" name="overseas" class="" onclick="chk_register1()" />
            <label>No</label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="no">
        <td>
            <label>11. How did you hear about it?</label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <textarea id="hcon" name="convention_source" value=""></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <label>12. How would you be paying your delegate fee?</label>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
            <input type="radio" class="" value="cheque" name="fee" checked="true" />
            <label>Members only)
                <br>cheque payable in name of
                <br>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" class="" value="bank transfer" name="fee" />
            <label>Bank Transfer</label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" colspan="4" style="color: red;font-size: 11px;">
            <div id="err11"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <input type="submit" name="sub" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my form , when a user click on the ARE YOU A MEMBER QUESTION IE YES  OR NO 
In NO , the whole table row which has id cit is getting hide but when the user click on the yes it will again show the whole table row but my problem is when the user click on NO and after that it will click on YES , table row is showing but it's showing me less width

```
<script>
    function chk_register() {
        if (document.getElementById('rchk1').checked) {
            document.getElementById("cit").style.display = "block";

        }
        if (document.getElementById('rchk2').checked) {
            document.getElementById("cit").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    function chk_register1() {
        if (document.getElementById('rchk3').checked) {
            document.getElementById("no").style.display = "block";
        }
        if (document.getElementById('rchk4').checked) {
            document.getElementById("no").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a table row `<tr>` to display `block` to show it. Instead you should use `table-row` because that is the default for a `<tr>`:

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ehCjN/)**

```
function chk_register(){
    if (document.getElementById('rchk1').checked) {
       document.getElementById("cit").style.display = "table-row";

    }
    if (document.getElementById('rchk2').checked) {
       document.getElementById("cit").style.display = "none";
    }
}
 function chk_register1(){
    if (document.getElementById('rchk3').checked) {
       document.getElementById("no").style.display = "table-row";
    }
    if (document.getElementById('rchk4').checked) {
       document.getElementById("no").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Side note: you should use the checkbox `onchange` event not `onclick`.